# import xlsx time in matlab

Tags: matlab, time, xlsx

I have a xlsx document in which the first column represents a time series:

2009-11-04 11:35:00.000

2009-11-04 11:36:00.000

2009-11-04 11:37:00.000

2009-11-04 11:38:00.000

when I read the xlsx file in matlab using the function:

[~,~,data] = xlsread(filename,1);

what I get is:

40121.4826388889

40121.4833333333

40121.4840277778

40121.4847222222

Which format is it? How can I get the time back?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`datestr`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html) function. For more information on dates and times in MATLAB, see [Represent Dates and Times in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/represent-date-and-times-in-MATLAB.html). Excel, however, has a different representation of dates from MATLAB, see [When to Convert Dates from Excel Files](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/import_export/when-to-convert-dates-from-excel-files.html) for more information.