# How to import ORIGINAL time data from .xlsx files to MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I've got a .xlsx file with parts like this:

[image]

I want to import that into MATLAB like this:

```
[data,txt,raw]=xlsread('filename','D1:D6')
```

But it becomes:

```
{'2019/5/26 8:17:41'}
{'2019/5/26 8:17:41'}
{'2019/5/26 8:17:41'}
{'2019/5/26 8:17:41'}
{'2019/5/26 8:17:41'}
{'2019/5/26 8:17:41'}
```

which rounds my original data to seconds, BUT I need to keep the milliseconds.

When I open the data file in Excel, I realized where the wrong data comes from. 
[image]

And now my question: **Is there a way to import the original data like `2019-05-26 08:17:40.501` into MATLAB?** Both datestr or datenum can be accepted, only if it contains the same thing with original data.

I can't find out any clue in `doc xlsread` or `doc importdata` to deal with this issue. Also I've seen [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655801/import-xlsx-time-in-matlab), which has similar data with mine but with totally different result, and I'd assume to be a different issue.

Comment: This has to have something to do with the formatting in Excel.  If you look at the Formula Bar in the Excel image you show, it is displaying the contents of cell D2 as  '2019/5/26 8:17:41', not what is actually showing in the cell itself.  I'll bet that  if you fix that then the data will read into MATLAB correctly.  I'd also suggest to use the more modern `readtable` instead of `xlsread`.

Comment: I fixed the issue with `readtable`, it gives me original data. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Phil Goddard, this issue is fixed with `readtable`, namely:

```matlab
raw=readtable('filename');
```

the result is a table

[image]

As you see, everything goes well. The time data is actually a `datetime` vector, which can be checked by `raw{:,4}`, and can be converted to datenum or datestr or anything you like.

**Generally, use `readtable` instead of `xlsread`.**

Comment: Note that `readtable` has optional inputs where you can specify the Range to read (just like `xlsread`) so you can just read in the data you want, not everything as you have done.